# Integrating NUnitTesting GUI to Visual studio 2012 and debugging Test Cases

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit-2.5

I am using NUnit 2.5 as my unit testing framework for visual studio 2012 professional.
I configured NUnit.exe to open NUnit GUI for testing my dlls.

I am testing a dll called "BookStore.dll" which i generated by compiling my current class library project "BookStore"

To configure nunit as my testing framework i set the following values in the BookStore library project properties window:

> Start External program: C:\Nunit\Nunit.exe
>
> Command line arguments : BookStore.dll
>
> working directory as : C:\Projects\BookStore\Bin\Debug\

i set the following configuration value in the nunit.exe.config

under configuration tag:

```
 <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
```

under runtime tag:

```
 <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
```

Now i set the start project as this library project and hit F5.
NUnit opens and i am able to select the project and test methods and i am able to hit run and see all the test results.

So far so good:

**but the problem is when i put a break point in any of the test method in the BookStore project, that break point is not hitting.**

**Can anybody help me what am i missing here.?**

Note: i configured this unit testing using this blog: http://blog.toddbauer.me/2011/02/17/debugging-net-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly hitting F5 and running the Test Project, I tried to run the project as this:

1. Put a breakpoint where ever needed.
2. Right click the Test project -> Debug -> Start new instance.

and then when i choose that appropriate test method and hit run, that enabled me to hit the breakpoint.

It works now.