# Customizing Visual Studio run configuration to run tests after launching application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, build-automation, coded-ui-tests

Here are the details of my Development Environment:

- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4

  Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m

  Windows 7 Professional with 32-bit Operating System

  Coded UITest Builder 11.0.60315.1

Microsoft Coded UITest Project is within the ASP.NET Web Application Solution.

We use the Microsoft Coded UITest Project to run Automated UI tests on the Web application.

Here is what needs to be done.

I need to build and run the ASP.NET Web Application Solution so that the Web Application will be deployed to Visual Studio Development server, and then ultimately show up in the Google Chrome Browser.  ( In other words, you highlight solution in Visual Studio and press F5 to build and run. )

The problem is that if I build and run the application, I want the aforementioned  Microsoft Coded UITest Project to run Automated UI tests after the Web Application is up and running.

Also, it's important to keep in mind that there needs to be a delayed start for the Automated UI tests because it will obviously take time for the Web Application to be up and running.

How can I automate the above using Visual Studio's build and run ( i.e pressing F5) process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using NUnit Framework instead of Microsoft Coded UI. However, I still use Selenium.

@alagesan-palani post ( [Integrating NUnitTesting GUI to Visual studio 2012 and debugging Test Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196712/integrating-nunittesting-gui-to-visual-studio-2012-and-debugging-test-cases) ) has helped me resolve my problem.

Moreover, @alagesan-palani was kind enough to post a the following link to a webpage that explains in some detail how to run NUnit test cases for the above problem:

http://blog.toddbauer.me/2011/02/17/debugging-net-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is a build server involved in that process and when you build your code you can specfiy whethere you wan tot run the tests or not after a sucessfull build.

Or you can do Test -> Test Settings -> Run Test after Build in Visual Studio.

Hope this helped

Comment: I already ensured that "Test -> Test Settings -> Run Test after Build in Visual Studio." was set.  However, when I press F5, it runs, and brings up my application, but my Microsoft CodedUI component with Selenium fails to automate. Furthermore, when the Visual Studio Development server launches the application, the options under Test-->Run--... and the options under Test-->Debug--...  are disabled( i.e. greyed out )

Comment: The only way is to create a local Build definition where you will set your test to run after build. Then you would need to build your project and the tests should run automatically aftrewards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I want the Microsoft CodedUI component with Selenium Test that I created to run every time Visual Studio Development server launches the application( i.e pressing F5). Your MSDN link talks about doing this with Team Foundation Server.  For my current problem, it does Not involve Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Are you able to create a local Build definition (where you will set  it to run the tests after completion)?