# Build, Launch ASP.NET Web application and run Microsoft CodedUI tests in efficient and less time-consuming manner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild, coded-ui-tests

Here are the details of my Development Environment:

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4

Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m

Windows 7 Professional with 32-bit Operating System

Coded UITest Builder 11.0.60315.1

Microsoft Coded UITest Project is within the ASP.NET Web Application Solution.

We use the Microsoft Coded UITest Project to run Automated UI tests on the Web application.

At present, I have the ASP.NET Web application in one Visual Studio 2012 solution file, and 
the Microsoft Coded UI Test Project with Selenium in another Visual Studio 2012 solution file.

So far, if I wanted to run the Automated UI tests, I take the following steps:

a) Open up the ASP.NET Web Application solution file in one instance of Visual Studio 2012

b) Press "F5" to build and then run the application in a Web Browser

c) Open up the Microsoft Coded UITest Project solution file in another Visual Studio 2012

d) From the main menu, click on the "Test" in main menu

e) Click on the Run in the menu that shows up

f) Click on the All tests in the other menu that shows up

The above steps can be seen as time-consuming, and inefficient since I'm opening up two instances of Visual Studio in order to conduct my testing.  I needed to figure out a way to be more efficient with my automated tests.

I've added my Microsoft Coded UI Test Project with Selenium to the ASP.NET Web Application Solution.  Moreover, I made the following configuration change:

"Test -> Test Settings -> Run Test after Build in Visual Studio."

However, Now, if I do a Build on the entire application, the Browser will open up, and give a "This webpage is not available" ( By the way, the reason for the said error makes sense because it when you do build solution, it will build the ASP.NET Web application and the Microsoft Coded UI module that was added, but it won't deploy the Web application to Visual Studio Development Server.  Therefore, when the build completes, it starts executing the Microsoft Coded UI test code which would initiate a browser to open up, but it will obviously give a "This webpage is not available" error because the Web application has Not been deployed to the Visual Studio Development Server. )

I'm trying to do the following steps:

1) Build the ASP.NET Web Application Solution

2) Deploy ASP.NET Web Application to Visual Studio Development server

3) Run the UI automated tests in the Microsoft Coded UITest Project

Is there an easy way to take on the aforementioned 3 steps by doing some configuration in Visual Studio with my ASP.NET WEb application? Or is there a way of doing this in MSBuild?  Efficiency and Less time-consuming steps are important otherwise conducting tests would be real waste of time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing Visual Studio run configuration to run tests after launching application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838133/customizing-visual-studio-run-configuration-to-run-tests-after-launching-applica)

Comment: This seems to be the same as you other question. Rather than asking another version of the same question you should add details to the original. If I have misunderstood and these really are different questions then please explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using NUnit Framework instead of Microsoft Coded UI.  However, I still use Selenium.

@alagesan-palani post (  [Integrating NUnitTesting GUI to Visual studio 2012 and debugging Test Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196712/integrating-nunittesting-gui-to-visual-studio-2012-and-debugging-test-cases)  ) has helped me resolve my problem.

Moreover, @alagesan-palani was kind enough to post a the following link to a webpage that explains in some detail how to run NUnit test cases for the above problem:

http://blog.toddbauer.me/2011/02/17/debugging-net-nunit-tests-in-visual-studio/